# Jenkins 'when' condition not working with stage environment

Tags: jenkins

I want to make a testing stage in Jenkins, but the when condition doesn't work with the environment variable set in the stage directly. If i set 'SOMEVAR' in the global environment everything works as expected. Following is a neutral version of my code, I'm using global environment variables and 'SOMEVAR' as an in-step variable (maybe this does matter).

```
    stage('TEST') {
        environment{
            SOMEVAR = '1'
        }
        when { 
            equals expected: '1', actual: env.SOMEVAR
        }
        steps {
            echo "IT WORKS"
            echo "$SOMEVAR"
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `when` directive is evaluated before `environment` in the stage.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that. I guess in my case I need to use a script step to fill some variables and use them with some if conditionals.

Comment: You can always do that but I am curious as to what prevents you from supplying the variable as a build parameter or top-level environment, unless you are generating the variable on the fly?